# Stuck with DNS questions during migration to AWS EC2 + Route 53

Tags: nameserver, cloudflare

We're running a little hosting service with two nameservers registered for us at a local registrar:

- ns1.ourcompany.com
- ns2.ourcompany.com

Now i want to move over to cloudflare with all the DNS services. From them, i got two new nameservers:

- lady.ns.cloudflare.com
- pete.ns.cloudflare.com

It is a killer requirement for us that we do not loose the existing two nameservers because they are already configured in customers top-level domains where we don't have access directly.

Now, i'm wondering what my options are:

1. Find out what ip's the two cloudflare servers really have and change the entries for our existing nameservers to these ip's -> pro, solved; con, the ip's can change and silently break my dns setup. More lookups are necessary to finally lookup a customers top level domain.
2. Making an CNAME alias for my existing nameserver to point to cloudflare servers directly, but this is against the RFC of DNS, no one will do that for me..
3. Pay a business account for at least 200$ per month at cloudflare to get custom named nameservers

Are there other DNS providers which has an API for automation and offers custom/vanity nameserver for a payable price per month?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you have two different business activities: web hosting and DNS hosting.  In order to use CloudFlare in front of your web hosting you have to hand over DNS hosting to them but you can't do this because you don't own all the domains using your nameservers and hence can't change which nameservers are used.  Have I got this right?

Comment: yes you got it right i think :) it is not completely impossible to change all the customers domain nameserver, but it is also a merkting thing - we really want to keep our current nameserver names.